40th Question IBM Sample test
Given this code fragment, what is the probability that the measurement would result in 1?
qc = QuantumCircuit(1)
qc.rz(3 * math.pi/4, 0)

A] 0
B] 0.14645
C] 0.85355
D] 1
With calculating using the absolute value of -isin(theta/2) I got the answer as B but the correct answer is A can someone pls help me solve this question?

Qubits are initially in the ∣0⟩ state. The Rz gate, which is a rotation around the z-axis, only changes the phase of the qubit states and not the probabilities of measuring 0 or 1 in the computational basis.

Thank you so much for the help
